# How to solve th(z)=0?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

Hyperbolic tangent
How to find all the solutions to th(z)=0 ? 
I do have the solution z=kπi but it does not make any sense to me

Comment: $\text{th}$ is also called $\tanh$, hyperbolic tangent.

Comment: Yes sir, nevertheless my issue here is th(z)=0 or tanh(z)=0 if you want...

Comment: $th(x)=\frac{sh(x)}{ch(x)}=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LINK](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function)
$$
\tanh z = \frac{e^{2z}-1}{e^{2z}+1}
$$
for complex number $z$.
Therefore
$\tanh z = 0$ if and only if $e^{2z}=1$.  That means $2z = 2\pi i n$ for some integer $n$, so $z = \pi i n$ for some integer $n$.  (Of course $i^2 = -1$ which we use to build the complex numbers.)

The only **real** number $z$ with $\tanh z = 0$ is $z=0$.  All other solutions are purely imaginary.